# Does the Java constructor return an object or an object's ID when called?

Tags: java

I want to know if a constructor in Java returns something. I know there is no return value like '5' or "Hello World." But if we are assigning a variable to it:

```
People person = new People();
```

Then wouldn't it logically make sense for the object or ID to be returned? Is the reference in memory where the object is stored assigned to people?

I am just thinking about this now because I am learning python, and want to connect the `__new__` method to a constructor and then `__init__` to the body of the constructor (i.e. the initial values). My professor keeps telling me `__new__` doesn't exist, so I am hoping to get an answer to make things clearer.

Comment: My suggestion is to not compare the specifics of each language like that. Python's `__new__` and `__init__` methods are quite different from most other languages' constructors. Especially with a language like python, where there's no such thing as a return type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java you only have primitives and references to objects as types for fields, parameters and local variables.  A reference is a bit like an ID, except it can change as any moment without you needing to know when this has happened.

A reference is closer to the concept of a pointer or object index. ie. it refers to a memory location.

`new` is definitely a keyword in Java, so saying it doesn't exist isn't very meaningful. You could say it doesn't have a one to one mapping in byte code, except byte code is itself run on a virtual machine and the machine actually run could be rather different anyway. i.e. there isn't much point treating byte code as the way things "really" happen.

Comment: sorry, the formatting messed it up. I meant _ _ new _ _ in python. He just ignored it completely and talked about _ _ init _ _ saying it created objects, but if it doesn't return an object, and is passed an object, how could it create it? That's why I wanted to associate _ _ new _ _ with creating objects

Comment: `talked about _ _ init _ _ saying it created objects, but if it doesn't return an object`. Technically that's not correct. the `__init__` method of a class returns `None`. And in python everything is a first class object.

Answer (score 1):

constructor is not "normal" method. And you must use operator `new` with constructor and then you will have reference to the object, so this is pointer (id) to the place in memory.

[here is some explanation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html)

> Constructor declarations look like method declarations—except that
>   they use the name of the class and have no return type

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no

More answer:  The thing that is "returning" something is the `new` operator.

When you create a new instance of a class (via the `new` operator), you must provide two pieces of information to the JVM: the name of the class to be instantiated and any parameters that are required to construct the new object (constructor parameters).

To allow for this, java requires the following syntax:

```
Type1 variableName = new Type2(parameter list);
```

In your example: `People person = new People();` People is the type of the reference named person and is the type of the object being instantiated (i.e. new People).  The constructor requires no parameters (a no-parameter constructor or default constructor) so the parameter list is "()".

Answer (score 0):

The return type of a constructor is the  **Class** itself.
You cannot consider them as void but its guaranteed to allocate memory on the heap and initialize the member fields , and finally returning the address of the newly allocated object which we use as reference variables.

Answer (score -1):

according to me, When the constructor used with 'new' keyword, it allocate the memory space for that object.

For Example: in your code `People person = new People();`

it automatically allocate the space required  for the newly created object 'person' in the memory.